# Facebook Page Tab using Shared SSL

Tags: facebook, ssl, shared

I'm trying to set up a page tab on my Facebook business page. Everything works fine except for the Secure Page Tab URL. I'm using a shared SSL from hostgator (https://secure623.websitewelcome.com/~username/). It works fine when I enter the url in my browser so I know it's valid, but when I try to enter it as the Secure Page Tab URL, I get an error stating the Secure Page Tab URL is not a valid URL. I've searched online for a solution but find conflicting answers.

I put in a ticket with Hostgator, but this is one of the few times they have been of no help. I've also sent an email to FB support but after 2 days haven't heard anything back.

Has anyone else come across this problem? If so, is there a way around it while still using the shared SSL?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm facing this problem too. Only FB can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The URL I use is: https://secure636.hostgator.com/~username/

That goes in the HTTPS field. The corresponding HTTP field is http://yourdomain.com

Answer (score 0):

Having same issue using Hostgator shared SSL.

Once you get the temp URL a htaccess mod rewrite is required.

These are what I've tried. I've been at it a week and only get warning and errors. HG support won't normally handle htaccess that's why I'm here. Your URL then should resolve https.

```
# Always use https for secure connections
# Replace 'www.example.com' with your domain name
# (as it appears on your SSL certificate)
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```